# sqlite3 overwrite a column with values from another column

Tags: sqlite, sql-update

I want to update an existing column with values from the corresponding rows in another column from another table.

```
sqlite> create table if not exists t1 (pk1 int, v1 float);
sqlite> insert into t1 values (1, 0.0), (2, 3.0);
sqlite> select * from t1;
1|0.0
2|3.0
sqlite> create table if not exists t2 (pk2 int, v2 float);
sqlite> insert into t2 values (1, 1.0), (3, 4.0);
sqlite> select * from t2;
1|1.0
3|4.0
sqlite> update t1 set v1 = t2.v2 where t1.pk1 = t2.pk2;
Error: no such column: t2.v2
```

I was expecting that in the row with pk1=1 in t1, the value in the v1 column would be changed to 1.0.
How do I overwrite one row with another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must explicitly select the column `v2` from the table `t2`:

```
update t1 
set v1 = (select t2.v2 from t2 where t1.pk1 = t2.pk2);
```

If there is no match between `t1.pk1` and `t2.pk2` and you don't want to perform the update in this case, because it will set `v1` to `null`, then use COALESCE():

```
update t1 
set v1 = coalesce((select t2.v2 from t2 where t1.pk1 = t2.pk2), t1.v1);
```

or `EXISTS`:

```
update t1 
set v1 = (select t2.v2 from t2 where t1.pk1 = t2.pk2)
where exists (select 1 from t2 where t1.pk1 = t2.pk2)
```

If your version of SQlite is 3.33+ you could do it with `UPDATE ... FROM`:

```
update t1
set v1 = t2.v2
from t2
where t1.pk1 = t2.pk2
```